# why chain not fall on the ground?

Tags: modifiers, rigidbody

With the chain as active and ground as passive created rigid body. Why the chain unable to drop on the floor. Chain is going through the mesh. Any suggestion whats going wrong

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For your ground you've chosen *Collisions* but *Collisions* is for *Cloth* or *Soft Body*, you need to choose *Rigid Body, Type > Passive and Shape > Mesh*.

Also, apply the ground scale and apply the chain modifiers (I'm not sure why it messes up the simulation though)

Comment: Why the chain is not flexible. Look so rigid (tight) when stand on the ground. Its not getting self collision like cloth. And dropping on the floor.

Comment: becaus if you want it to act like a real chain you would need to make each chain link an independent object

Comment: if you want to make a chain, follow this tutorial for example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=18PDK5ekEWc ... you could also try to fake it with a cloth simulation + Surface Deform?

Answer (score 3):

There are many reasons why your mesh is falling through the floor.  After examining your file, I figured out all of the problems, and I will tell you how to fix them.

first off, when I downloaded your file, your plane did not have any rigidbody physics attached to it, so if your plane does not have passive rigidbody physics, then that is the first thing you need to fix.  (also, make sure the collision for both objects is set to "mesh" in the rigidbody settings)

Next, your chain mesh has a lot of modifiers on it that are messing with the rigidbody simulation and confusing the computer.  to ensure a smooth and good looking simulation, go to the modifiers tab on your chain object, and apply all of your modifiers.

After that, it should work like it's supposed to. Hope this helped! :)  If you encounter further problems on this topic, feel free to let me know.

Comment: Why the chain is not flexible. Look so rigid (tight) when stand on the ground. Its not getting self collision like cloth. And dropping on the floor.

Comment: This is because your chain is one object.  It's not going to calculate the physics for each individual chain if there is only one object.  If you want each link to have their own physics, then the way I would do it is make a single chain link, and then give that link rigidbody physics.  then use an array modifier along your bezier curve. Make sure to apply your modifiers.  Next, go into edit mode, select everything, Press "P" on your keyboard, and click on "by loose parts"  All of the chains should now be separate with their own individual physics.